# Can I use a single call to munmap() to unmap two memory mappings located in a contiguous range of virtual memory?

Tags: linux, macos, posix, mmap

For example, if I do this:

```
  char *pMap1;          /* First mapping */
  char *pReq;           /* Address we would like the second mapping at */
  char *pMap2;          /* Second mapping */

  /* Map the first 1 MB of the file. */
  pMap1 = (char *)mmap(0, 1024*1024, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  assert( pMap1!=MAP_FAILED );

  /* Now map the second MB of the file. Request that the OS positions the
  ** second mapping immediately after the first in virtual memory.  */
  pReq = pMap1 + 1024*1024;
  pMap2 = (char *)mmap(pReq, 1024*1024, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 1024*1024);
  assert( pMap2!=MAP_FAILED );

  /* Unmap the mappings created above. */
  if( pMap2==pReq ){
    munmap(pMap1, 2 * 1024*1024);
  }else{
    munmap(pMap1, 1 * 1024*1024);
    munmap(pMap2, 1 * 1024*1024);
  }
```

And the OS does place my second mapping in the requested position (so
that the (pMap2==pReq) condition is true), will the single call to
munmap() serve to release all resources allocated?

The Linux man page says "The munmap() system call deletes the mappings
for the specified address range...", which suggests that this will work,
but I'm still a little nervous about it. Even if it does work on Linux,
does anybody know how portable this is likely to be?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The glibc manual says it's fine:

> **munmap** removes any memory maps from (addr) to (addr + length). length
> should be the length of the mapping.
>
> It is safe to unmap multiple
> mappings in one command, or include unmapped space in the range. It is
> also possible to unmap only part of an existing mapping. However, only
> entire pages can be removed.

Answer (score 4):

The POSIX spec [says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/munmap.html):

> ```
> int munmap(void *addr, size_t len);
> ```
>
> The `munmap()` function shall remove **any mappings for those entire pages containing any part of the address space of the process starting at `addr` and continuing for `len` bytes.**

To me, the wording clearly reads as if removing multiple mappings with a single `munmap()` is fine, and should be supported by any compliant implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should work. The [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/munmap.html) says that it removes

> any mappings for those entire pages containing any part of the address space of the process starting at `addr` and continuing for `len` bytes

The only unspecified behavior it describes is:

> The behavior of this function is unspecified if the mapping was not established by a call to `mmap()`.